# HTML mail signature influences blacklisted SPAM?

Tags: html, email, blacklist

I had a several *Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender* with my domain. This started happening at least 2 months, after I made an HTML signature.

It is possible, I don't know very well the sense of this. My e-mail signature only as a link with my site name and a PNG of brand logo (13kb). So if you guys could help me with this I will be very gratful.

This is the returned to sender (the most usual):

```
DOMAIN is blacklisted on Spamhaus - see
www.spamhaus.org
    (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

I checked my domain on their site and is not listed (idiot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you're seeing is in regards to [The Spamhaus Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spamhaus_Project), which compiles and distributes lists of IP's and domains associated with [email spam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spam) so that email servers can filter them out.

Unlike content-matching tools like [SpamAssassin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpamAssassin), which uses a variety of spam-detection techniques (including analyzing the content of the message), filtering based on [DNS-based Blocklists (DNSBLs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL) as provided by Spamhaus is based on IP or domain instead of the message body or signature therein.

Looking at the [SMTP transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#Protocol_overview), the response `(in reply to RCPT TO command)` seems to indicate that the recipient(s) domain is blacklisted on Spamhaus, so I would check the domains of the email addresses that you're sending to with the [Spamhaus Domain Lookup Tool](http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/).

It might also be a good idea to check the domain and IP address that your sending from and the SMTP server you're using if you're getting other rejection responses.