# Adding an SMTP server that would result in more delivered emails

Tags: php, email, smtp, joomla3

I am very curious, so sorry if I am asking this in the wrong way, but I can't find this info anywhere.

I have a newsletter service installed in my Joomla 3.1 that allows me to send emails via PHP mailer. In the last few days, I figured out that at least 30% of my sent emails were blocked (and so my domain IP).

So I asked myself the meaning of changing mailer method to SMTP (the configuration in my Joomla allows me to do this), but here's a question: how could I install an SMTP server in my host (with cPanel) resulting in more delivered e-mails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server that's hosting cPanel has the same IP address as your domain, and that IP address is blacklisted (as covered previously [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53147/html-mail-signature-influences-blacklisted-spam)), then you should try to send email using another IP address, or use an SMTP server with a different IP address that's not blacklisted.

If you request an additional IP address from your web host (that's not blacklisted), you can configure Exim in cPanel to use that IP instead - see: [Changing the Sending IP for Outbound Email in Exim](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/EximDifferentIps)

Your web hosting company (or ISP) may also provide an external SMTP that you can relay through which you could use in your mailer - check their FAQ's or support knowledge-base.

If your domain is also blacklisted however, in addition to your IP, using another IP address or SMTP may still result in emails being rejected with your domain in the *from* address. So it would be wise to check both your domain and IP address on a multi-RBL check like this [one](http://www.anti-abuse.org/multi-rbl-check/), and request they be removed by each site that it shows up on.

Comment: thank you so much. I checked if my host is blocked **before** ask this question, happily I am not blocked in any server. The question remains in a topic: the best mailler method for e-mail recipients (improving percentage of delivered emails), is _php mail_ or _STMP Server_, and if is a YES to _SMTP_, how can I configure it in my host? I read something that says that SMTP is the best method, but I can't figure it.

Comment: No problem. It seemed from this: `my sent e-mails were blocked (and so my domain IP)`, and your previous question, that your domain or IP was being blocked. I'm not sure what PHP mailer you're using, but most require either an SMTP server to be specified or they use the local mail transfer agent (MTA) on the system, which also uses [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol).

Comment: In cPanel, the MTA is [Exim](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/EximConfig). 
By default it's configured when you create email accounts, and typically named something like "mail.example.com", but might require authentication to use with scripts. As far as configuring it to avoid being blocked, see [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-can-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-classified-as-spam).